# Check whether recieve inputStreamReader is object or string

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I am working on a client-server communication application.  From one side I am trying to send strings and objects - not at the same time - so that at the receiver end I get data from the socket.  This is where the problem is.  How can I know whether the data is a string or an object?

```
mIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Unless you have established a message format, the only solution is to read the incoming message into a byte[] and then examine to determine if it's an Object or a String.

Comment: Nowise. You are transfering chain of bits only, there is no information related to transfered object type. To solve this you need to implement simple protocol (transfer type of data with your data) or use exist protocols (REST, protobuf etc.).